# RDF Data for online NEWS sites

Tags: rdf, semantics

I want to get the list of major news sites in different languages. Is there any provider who provides most of the major website details in RDF format?

Comment: RSS 1.0 is pure RDF, so you could look for sites that provide that. Otherwise you could try searching http://sindice.com for classes or properties that have to do with news. My guess is that the New York Times would come up, as they were involved with the rNews vocabulary that can be used in microdata or RDFa in HTML to markup articles etc.

Comment: Wait, you were asking for a set of triples about news organisations...

Comment: @BenCompanjen, Yes I am trying to find out all( or as many as we get) the news sites. I am building an application in which I want to know which one is a news site. If it is news site then I have to disable the caching of the pages. So If I have the news domains with me then I won't cache all those pages from those news sites.

Comment: Isn't that off topic for a programming Q&A like SO?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know about the scope of the questions that have to be asked. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia contains information from Wikipedia, and has a SPARQL endpoint.  There are some relevant categories in Wikipedia that might help you find the sort of information that you are looking for.  For instance, we can select individual news sites and get 302 results:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?newsSite dcterms:subject category:News_websites .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%2a+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3FnewsSite+dcterms%3Asubject+category%3ANews_websites+.%0D%0A%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

It is a bit more difficult to reliably get out other pieces of information, since some information might not be available for a page, or the same information might be present on different pages with different properties.  For instance, some of those pages record their news site with `dbpprop:web`

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?newsSite dcterms:subject category:News_websites .
  OPTIONAL { ?newsSite dbpprop:web ?web }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+%2a+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++++%3FnewsSite+dcterms%3Asubject+category%3ANews_websites+.%0D%0A++++++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3FnewsSite+dbpprop%3Aweb+%3Fweb+%7D%0D%0A++++%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Others use `dbpprop:website`.  You could just replace `dbpprop:web` in the previous query with `dbpprop:web|dbpprop:website`, although that runs somewhat slowly on the DBpedia endpoint.  You can be more verbose and use this instead:

```
SELECT ?newsSite ?web WHERE { 
  ?newsSite dcterms:subject category:News_websites .
  OPTIONAL { 
    { ?newsSite dbpprop:web ?web }
    UNION
    { ?newsSite dbpprop:website ?web }

  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+%3FnewsSite+%3Fweb+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++++%3FnewsSite+dcterms%3Asubject+category%3ANews_websites+.%0D%0A++++++OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A++++++++%7B+%3FnewsSite+dbpprop%3Aweb+%3Fweb+%7D%0D%0A++++++++UNION%0D%0A++++++++%7B+%3FnewsSite+dbpprop%3Awebsite+%3Fweb+%7D%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This still only gets websites for a handful of these pages.  Some more use `dbpprop:url`, so we have the following:

```
SELECT ?newsSite ?web WHERE { 
  ?newsSite dcterms:subject category:News_websites .
  OPTIONAL { 
    { ?newsSite dbpprop:web ?web }
    UNION
    { ?newsSite dbpprop:website ?web }
    UNION 
    { ?newsSite dbpprop:url ?web }
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+%3FnewsSite+%3Fweb+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++++%3FnewsSite+dcterms%3Asubject+category%3ANews_websites+.%0D%0A++++++OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A++++++++%7B+%3FnewsSite+dbpprop%3Aweb+%3Fweb+%7D%0D%0A++++++++UNION%0D%0A++++++++%7B+%3FnewsSite+dbpprop%3Awebsite+%3Fweb+%7D%0D%0A++++++++UNION+%0D%0A++++++++%7B+%3FnewsSite+dbpprop%3Aurl+%3Fweb+%7D%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thank you so much.. I will use this one.